# sql-server-2005: How to perform a split on a pipe delimited string variable?

Tags: sql, string, sql-server-2005

i have simple data coming in like this:

```
declare @string varchar(500) = "val1|val2|val3"
```

how could i split this out into a cte or something similar so i could user it in a later query:

```
select col1 from table where col2 = @valFromCTE
```

Comment: Use a split function. You can see an example in my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7274514/sql-query-to-match-keywords

Comment: ok, i am having a little trouble, because mine is a raw input string thoough

Comment: right, i am looking at the numbers table that is where i am tripping

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a helpful and simple way to query a delimited string as if it were a table.

Taken from:
http://www.mindsdoor.net/SQLTsql/ParseCSVString.html

```
if exists (select * from dbo.sysobjects where id = object_id(N'[dbo].[fn_ParseCSVString]') and xtype in (N'FN', N'IF', N'TF'))
drop function [dbo].[fn_ParseCSVString]
GO


create function fn_ParseCSVString
(
@CSVString  varchar(8000) ,
@Delimiter  varchar(10)
)
returns @tbl table (s varchar(1000))
as
/*
select * from dbo.fn_ParseCSVString ('qwe,c,rew,c,wer', ',c,')
*/
begin
declare @i int ,
    @j int
    select  @i = 1
    while @i <= len(@CSVString)
    begin
        select  @j = charindex(@Delimiter, @CSVString, @i)
        if @j = 0
        begin
            select  @j = len(@CSVString) + 1
        end
        insert  @tbl select substring(@CSVString, @i, @j - @i)
        select  @i = @j + len(@Delimiter)
    end
    return
end


GO
```

Comment: Just to be pedantic, while on small strings it is likely irrelevant, I'd be conscious of performance implications of looping methods on larger strings. While I did this for `INT` values, I compared the performance of various splitting methods last year and you should check the results: https://sqlblog.org/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2010/07/07/splitting-a-list-of-integers-another-roundup.aspx