# Basic pattern recognition in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, regex, substring

I currently have my data stored in this format :

```
Word1 - Word2 - Number.I.Need.To.Extract.Separated.By.Periods - Word3 - Word4
```

What I would like to do is write an update statement that will set a column which I have just created to `Number.I.Need.To.Extract.Separated.By.Periods`.

What is my best way to do this, or work like this?

I have tried to write it as follows :

```
UPDATE Table1
SET NewColumn = 
               (SELECT SUBSTRING(Column, 19, 14)
                FROM Table1)
```

Which results in :

> Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the
>   subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as
>   an expression. The statement has been terminated.

How can I fix this ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=subquery+returns+more+than+one+row&submit=search

Comment: possible duplicate of [sql-server-2005: How to perform a split on a pipe delimited string variable?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7391473/sql-server-2005-how-to-perform-a-split-on-a-pipe-delimited-string-variable)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need the subquery as the update occurs "inside" the same row.

Doesn't this work?

```
UPDATE Table1 SET NewColumn = SUBSTRING(Column, 19, 14)
```

Answer (score 0):

When it comes to text analysis and string manipulations , [regular expressions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c75he57e) provide a much more efficient and elegant solution than TSQL string functions.

You can write a [CLR User-Defined Function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131077.aspx) which extracts a pattern matching string.

```
UPDATE Table1 SET NewColumn = fn_ExtractPatternMatchingString(Column,pattern)
```