# activerecord-sqlserver-adapter unicode slow performance

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sql-server, performance, activerecord, unicode

I'm on Rails 3.2.18 and MRI-Ruby-2.0.0

Gemfile:

```
gem 'tiny_tds'
gem 'activerecord-sqlserver-adapter'
```

$ gem list | grep -E "tds|sql"

```
activerecord-sqlserver-adapter (3.2.12)
sqlite3 (1.3.9)
tiny_tds (0.6.2)
```

database.yml:

```
development:
  adapter: sqlserver
  database: DBTEST
  username: domain\username
  password: somepwd
  host: myhostname
  port: 1433
  timeout: 180000
```

Problem: Queries take too long to complete. See:

```
> MyModel.find_all_by_NRPIS '12700333166'
  MyModel Load (85869.3ms)  EXEC sp_executesql N'SELECT [MyTable].* FROM [MyTable] WHERE [MyTable].[NRPIS] = N''12700333166'''
```

So I see the problem is in `N` unicode conversions, because when I query without it, its really fast, see:

```
   >> ActiveRecord::Base.connection.select_all   "SELECT [MyTable].* FROM [MyTable] WHERE [MyTable].[NRPIS] = '12700333166'" }
   (62.5ms)  EXEC sp_executesql N'SELECT [MyTable].* FROM [MyTable] WHERE [TBCAGEDTrabalhador].[NRPIS] = ''12700333166'''

   >> ActiveRecord::Base.connection.select_all   "SELECT [MyTable].* FROM [MyTable] WHERE [MyTable].[NRPIS] = N'12700333166'" }
   (102324.0ms)  EXEC sp_executesql N'SELECT [MyTable].* FROM [MyTable] WHERE [MyTable].[NRPIS] = N''12700333166'''
```

**What is happening here and how can I solve the issue ?**

I have seen [THIS QUESTION](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8996224/sp-executesql-with-n-arguments-is-causing-slow-performance), but I would really like to tell sqlserver-adapter not to convert anything to unicode.

Answer (score 3):

Found it.

The issue has been discussed here: [disabling N'...' quoting for strings #124](https://github.com/rails-sqlserver/activerecord-sqlserver-adapter/issues/124)

Problem is quoting of utf-8 strings. Besides from the solution above, maybe you can force other encoding so that strings don't get quoted, something like:

```
> a = MyModel.where "NRPIS = ?", '12700233166'.force_encoding("ISO-8859-1")
 MyModel Load (53.1ms)  EXEC sp_executesql N'SELECT [MyTable].* FROM [MyTable] WHERE (NRPIS = ''12700193166'')'
```

As additional info, the table which MyModel refers to has no primary_keys defined, only a Index for NRPIS.

I've notice that when I query against tables that have primary_keys defined and you query exactly the primary_keys, the index is NOT ignored and the query runs fast even with unicode quoting.